# Cross-referencing Facebook User IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I seem to recall that after the publicized privacy concern with Facebook Apps and leaked User IDs that Facebook announced it was considering a change. This change, if I recall, would be that Apps would receive rewritten User IDs instead of actual User IDs. Did anything come of this? Links to official statements and/or developer documentation clarifying this would be appreciated.

In short, I would like to build out two separate applications that are closely related to one another, and I want to be able to cross-reference User IDs between these two applications (if possible). Is there a best practice for doing this?

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: I would argue it's an API question, and an (implicit) best practice question given my described use case. I can edit to emphasize the question around my use case if you think that will be better?

Comment: I see what you are trying to get at, but you are asking stuff specific to Facebook. From the StackOverflow FAQ:     a specific programming problem
    a software algorithm
    software tools commonly used by programmers
    matters that are unique to the programming profession

Comment: I believe I've got my answer, and this question is probably in a gray area of the described/cited intended-Q&A. I will vote to close as well, letting the rest of the community decide the fate of this Q (in case there are others who may find it useful). Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post that should provide some guidance.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/431/

> Currently, we pass iframe applications the `fb_sig_user` query string parameter in the URL. This allows the application to identify the user and create customized, social experience. Due to the way browsers work, this information in the URL can be inadvertently passed in the HTTP Referrer header when someone clicks a link within the iframe.
>
> Our initial proposal to address this issue used encryption as a means to protect against this inadvertent sharing, but still passed this encrypted UID in the URL. After talking with the community, we have updated our proposed solution to use a different mechanism that provides better protection for users while minimizing the impact on existing applications and eliminates the need to use encryption libraries.
>
> In short, this new proposal embeds the UID in a HTTP POST body ensuring that it will not be exposed in any HTTP Referrer header whatsoever (encrypted or otherwise). We do this by creating a `<form/>` element targeted at the application Canvas URL:
>
> ```
>  <form target="canvas_iframe" action="http://example.com/" id="canvas_form">
>      <input name="fb_sig_user" value="1234" type="hidden" />
>  </form>
>  <iframe name="canvas_iframe"></iframe>
>  <script>
>      document.getElementById("canvas_form").submit()
>  </script>
> ```